# Sheremetyevo (SVO) Airport transit zone temperature

Tags: airports, weather-and-climate, clothing, svo

On next days I will stop in Sheremetyevo SVO Airport for a flight connection.
I have to wait for about 5 hours in the transit zone during the night and I'm wondering what's the climate like inside. Is there a comfortable 20+ Celsius degrees or is it cold?
Should I take a coat or jacket with me?

I don't plan to sleep in the capsule hotel.

Comment: I have been Shermetyevo lots and never noticed it being overly cold; the temperature is the same as any other airport.  I always travel with a Barbour Beaufort anyway, and thus for your question "should I take a coat or jacket with me", the answer is invariably yes.

Comment: Inside the airport transit zone the temperature is normal, and you probably no need a coat there. However, you should remember, that some airboard doesn't use a corridor between airport and craft, so you might travel between airport and aircraft by using shuttle bus. And those buses are super cold inside.

Comment: @MikkaRin you could put that as an answer...

Answer (score 8):

Inside the airport transit zone the temperature is normal, and you probably do not need a coat there.

However, you should remember, that some airlines don't use the jetway/airbridge, so you might have to travel between the terminal and the aircraft by using a shuttle bus. Those buses are super cold inside.